# Пример простого Get и Post запроса

Tags: php, http

В php знаю только основы. Сейчас понадобилось поработать с запросами. Просто хочу увидеть примеры обработки этих запросов и как это работает. Додумал до этого:

```
<?php
 echo "Привет, $_GET['name'] !";
?>
```

В браузере ввожу `http://localhost/script.php?name=Vasiliy`. Вроде должно быть "Привет Vasiliy", но выходит ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in Z:\home\localhost\www\get.php on line 2

В чем ошибка? Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры простых Get и Post запросов. Использование форм пока не планирую, хочу с адресной строки браузера. И пожалуйста, не забудьте коменты. ))

Comment: post запрос из адресной строки... круть.

Comment: Мда(((( сглупил с кавычками((( тупо... А как насчет Post? Разницу меж post И get понимаю.

Comment: @hooko, тогда вы должны понимать и то, что из адресной строки POST не отправляется.

Comment: про адресную строку я имел ввиду get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
echo "Привет, $_GET[name] !"; // Первый вариант
echo 'Привет, '.$_GET['name'].' !'; // Второй вариант
?>
```

Comment: @hooko, `$_POST` - массив данных переданных через пост-запрос

Comment: <?php
 echo "Привет, {$_GET['name']} !"; //Третий вариант
?>

Comment: echo "Привет, ",$_GET['name']; //пятый и самый верный )

Comment: Да примеров может быть немерянно. Еще один:

    printf('Привет %s!', $_GET['name']);

`printf` и `sprintf` подойдет в том случае если строка приветствия задается как константа в отдельном модуле. Особенно полезно если делаешь мультиязычный сайт.

И все эти примеры верные если интерпретатор не выводит ошибку :). Главное понимать как каждый из них работает, и что в той или иной ситуации строит использовать.

Answer (score 1):

$_GET - глобальный массив для get запросов.

$_POST - глобальный массив для post запросов.

$_REQUEST - глобальный массив для get и post запросов.

**get:**

```
адресная строка:  some_site.com?var=hello
```

**код:**

```
echo $_GET['var'];//hello
echo $_REQUEST['var'];//hello
echo $_POST['var'];//Notice: Undefined index: var in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 echo "Привет, {$_GET['name']} !";
?>
```

Нужно заэкранировать переменную в данном случае по такому примеру. Удачи.